# Symmetric product of a $k-$algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, definition

What is the definition of symmetric product of a $k-$algebra? I read form somewhere that $S^n (k[x]/x^2)=k[x]/x^{n+1}$ but I only know the symmetric product of a vector space. What is the definition of the ring structure here?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra

Comment: In the section "Analogy with exterior algebra" of the wiki page, there is a formula for the dimension. Notice that $\dim(k[x]/x^i)=i$ and that formula indeed works for the above.

Comment: @Mathematician42 But my question is about the ring structure, which your formula didn't tell.

Comment: Ah now I see, hmm weird. Are you sure that $S^n(k[x]/x^2)$ is supposed to have a ring structure? Perhaps the isomorphism $S^n(k[x]/x^2)\cong k[x]/x^{n+1}$ is simply a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: @Mathematician42 In fact I am not very sure. That's also why I ask :)

Comment: My guess is that it's simply supposed to be a vector spaces isomorphism, not as algebras.

Comment: @Mathematician42 yeah, maybe you are right